# How to take a screenshot with Selenium-Chrome ("--headless")

Tags: selenium, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I have created an application using Selenium. The application opens chrome and goes to 3 different websites and captures a screenshot. It all works great. but as soon as add the headless argument so chrome will run in the background the application proceeds and saves the first image but then when it goes to the second website it throws me a system out of memory exception "out of memory" on this line of code ("using (var clone = screenshot.Clone(croppedImage, screenshot.PixelFormat))").

If someone could indicate to me what I have to do/read to solve the problem that would be greatly appreciated.

```cs
public void TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, string filename)
        {
            // Scroll to the element if necessary
            var actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.MoveToElement(element);
            actions.Perform();
            // Get the element position (scroll-aware)
            var locationWhenScrolled = ((RemoteWebElement)element).LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView;
            var fileName = filename + ".png";
            var byteArray = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
            Class_Timer.MyTimer();
            using (var screenshot = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)))
            {
                var location = locationWhenScrolled;
                // Fix location if necessary to avoid OutOfMemory Exception
                if (location.X + element.Size.Width > screenshot.Width)
                {
                    location.X = screenshot.Width - element.Size.Width;
                }
                if (location.Y + element.Size.Height > screenshot.Height)
                {
                    location.Y = screenshot.Height - element.Size.Height;
                }
                Class_Timer.MyTimer();
                // Crop the screenshot
                var croppedImage = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(location.X, location.Y, element.Size.Width, element.Size.Height);
                using (var clone = screenshot.Clone(croppedImage, screenshot.PixelFormat))
                {
                    clone.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                    Class_Timer.MyTimer();
                    clone.Dispose(); 

                }
                screenshot.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Comment: did you added the chrome options for headless? chromeOptions.addArguments("screenshot"); AND chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1980,960");

Comment: Yes, I have added these arguments